# invalid changeset in seeds.ex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run this in my seeds.ex

```
Repo.insert!(%User{
  email: "aadmin@aadmin.com",
  username: "aadmin"
})

Repo.insert!(%User{
  email: "Jack@Jack.com",
  username: "Jack"
})

Repo.insert!(%User{
  email: "Jill@Jill.com",
  username: "Jill"
})

Repo.insert!(%Task{
  title: "test",
  owner_id: 1,
  assignee_id: 2,
  status_id: 2
})

Repo.insert!(%Management{
  manager_id: 1,
  managed_id: 2
})
```

this is my management.ex

```
schema "managements" do
    belongs_to(:manager_id, User)
    belongs_to(:managed_id, User)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(%Management{} = management, attrs) do
    management
    |> cast(attrs, [:manager_id, :managed_id])
    |> validate_required([:manager_id, :managed_id])
  end
```

and this is my user.ex

```
schema "users" do
    field(:email, :string)
    field(:username, :string)
    has_one(:manager_user, Management, foreign_key: :manager_id)
    has_many(:managed_user, Management, foreign_key: :managed_id)
    has_one(:managers, through: [:manager_user, :manager])
    has_many(:manageds, through: [:managed_user, :managed])

    timestamps()
  end
```

When I try to `mix ecto.reset` it will tell me `could not perform insert because changeset is invalid.`
along with

```
Applied changes

    %{}

Params

    nil

Errors

    %{manager_id: ["is invalid"]}

Changeset

    #Ecto.Changeset<
      action: :insert,
      changes: %{},
      errors: [manager_id: "is invalid"],
      data: #Tasktracker.Accounts.Management<>,
      valid?: false
    >
```

but I filled out the manager_id and managed_id with valid ids of users that were just created above it. I don't understand why its not showing even the ids in the error and only telling me "is invalid"

Please explain what is wrong with my

```
Repo.insert!(%Management{
  manager_id: 1,
  managed_id: 2
})
```

Comment: Which line of code exactly produced that error? AFAIK a plain `Repo.insert!` should not produce an error that includes a changeset.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` in Elixir is a bare `map` underneath and maps in Elixir cannot have same keys:

```
%Management{manager_id: 1, managed_id: 2}
%{foo: 42, foo: :bar}
```

all the above is invalid. It has nothing to do with `Ecto`, database, or `Repo`: it’s an Elixir pure syntax issue. (Technically, it’s not invalid, it just discards the former value and uses the latter, try foo-example in `iex` to see the issue.) As a result, your `Management` struct has only one `manager_id: 2` field, making the association invalid.

To overcome the problem, you should grant the relations with unique names.